# XML/XHTML replace content?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a XHTML string I want to replace tags in
for example

```
<span tag="x">FOO</span> 
<span tag="y"> <b>bar</b> some random text <span>another span</span> </span>
```

I want to be able to find  tag="x"   and replace FOO with my own content
and find tag=y  and replace all the inner content with by own content.

What is the best way to do this? I am thinking regex is definitely out of the question.
Can XPATH do this or is that just for searching can it do manipulation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sure the content is XHTML (i.e. well-formed XML) then XPath can certainly do it.

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<span tag=...");

foreach(var node in doc.SelectNodes("//span[tag=x]"))
{
    node.InnerXml = "New Content";
}
foreach(var node in doc.SelectNodes("//span[tag=y]"))
{
    node.InnerXml = "Different Content";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer plus the sample code. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can surely do this using regular expressions (it is a string manipulation afterall), but that may get a bit nasty, because HTML can be quite complicated. However, it is certainly a possible approach.

An alternative would be to parse the XHTML page into some structured hieararchy and then do the processing. The question is whether the pages are *really* valid XML. The XHTML specification requires that, but if you'll pick random page from the internet that claims to be XHTML, you may run into troubles.

- If no, then you need to parse them as HTML, which can be done using [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).
- If yes, then you can treat it as XML and use standard .NET classes to parse it.

The second case could be done using LINQ to XML like this:

```
var xs = from span in doc.Descendant("span")
         let tag = span.Attribute("tag")
         where tag != null && tag.Value == "x" select span;
forach(var x in xs) x.Value = "BAR!";
```

The obvious benefit is that this is much more readable and maintainable than a solution that would use regular expressions. Html Agility Pack provides a similar API (although I'm not familiar with it to write a sample).

Comment: [No](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).  **You CAN'T do it with regular expressions**.

Comment: This has to be linked when HTML and RegEx are mentioned in the same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Hehe, great reference :-), but there _are_ cases where I would use regular expressions (if it wasn't _really_ XML and I needed a quick hack rather than solid solution). The title should really be **You'll burn in hell if you do it using regular expressions**. To me, "can't" and "regular expressions" in one sentence suggests that there should be a proof ;-)

Comment: @John Saunders: I see that he means "XHTML", but this is the world of so called "web standards".

Comment: @Tomas: I think there's a fair chance that something calling itself XHTML will a some point be consumed by an XML parser, which, if it's not valid XML, will tell you. I see no reason to confuse readers by suggesting there are valid times to use regular expressions when parsing XHTML.

Comment: Yes I give one vote  for Tomas as it is a valid point the file may not be valid XML ( I will have to double check this as it is user provided content from ckEditor) Thanks for providing the LINQ code sample and showing me about Html Agility Pack. Thank you,